# Why is .qcow2 image larger (+1920000 bytes) after resising the image via `qemu-img resize --shrink`?

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I created 20 GiB `.qcow2` image for my virtual machine. Next I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. The system uses ~8 GiB, so I decided to shrink the image to 10 GiB using the following command:

```
# qemu-img resize --shrink ubuntu20.04.qcow2 10241M
```

The value of 10241M was calculated using the last sector of the partition that was shrinked in `gparted` (using the Ubuntu live system inside the virtual machine). The last sector was `20973567` so ((20973567+1)×512)/1024/1024 = 10241 MiB.

As a result of the `qemu-img resize --shrink` command I got the following image:

```
# ls -al ubuntu20.04.qcow2
    -rw------- 1 root root 10740432896 2020-08-04 20:26:46 ubuntu20.04.qcow2
```

The size here (`10740432896`) is 10242.875 MiB and it's larger (+1920000 bytes) compared to the virtual size, which can be checked via:

```
# qemu-img info ubuntu20.04.qcow2

image: ubuntu20.04.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 10 GiB (10738466816 bytes)
disk size: 9.19 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

So here 10738466816 bytes is exacty 10241 MiB.

So where the 1920000 bytes come from?